# Add ordinal column to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'd like to add a column to a stored procedure that simply counts up from 1, irrespective of how the data is sorted or which page I'm fetching (using offset.)

The stored procedure itself looks like this:

```
SELECT  
   e.EntityId, e.HierarchyId, e.ParentNode, e.NgageId, e.NgageParentId,
   e.Type, e.IsDeleted, e.LastIndexedDate, e.CurrentVersion, e.Level, 
   v.EntityVersionID, v.VerisonNotes, v.Title, v.[Description], v.FormID, 
   v.IsPublic, v.CreatedDate, v.LastModifiedDate, v.ExpirationDate, 
   d.DocumentID, d.OwnerId AS OwnerId, 
   o.ADUsername AS OwnerAccount, o.Name AS Author, 
   d.[Status], d.DocumentType, d.CheckoutUserId AS CheckoutUserId, 
   c.ADUsername AS CheckoutUserAccount, c.Name AS CheckoutUserName, 
   d.CheckoutDate,
   dbo.GetCommaSeperatedTags(e.EntityID) AS Tags
   --INTO #documentsTemp 
FROM 
   dbo.Entities AS e
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.EntityVersions AS v ON v.EntityID = e.EntityID AND e.CurrentVersion = v.VersionNumber
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Documents AS d ON d.EntityVersionID = v.EntityVersionID
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Users AS o ON o.UserID = d.OwnerId
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.Users AS c ON c.UserID = d.CheckoutUserId
WHERE 
   [Type] = 5 
   AND NgageID = @ngageId 
   AND IsDeleted = 0
   AND dbo.CheckPermissions(e.EntityId, @userId, 'LIST') = 1
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'Title' THEN v.Title END,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'Title' AND @desc = 1 THEN v.Title END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'Author' THEN o.Name END,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'Author' AND @desc = 1 THEN o.Name END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'DateModified' THEN v.LastModifiedDate END,
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'DateModified' AND @desc = 1 THEN v.LastModifiedDate END DESC
OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: You should probably do this at the application level.  `row_number()` will assign a row number, but you would have to repeat the `order by` clause and do arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three options (two of them are already mentioned by Gordon and the third one is not recommended):

1. do this at the application level
2. repeat the ORDER BY clause and do some arithmetic
3. rely on undocumented behaviour, with potentially incorrect results

Here are options 2 and 3 in AdventureWorks (to shorten the queries):

```
DECLARE @pageSize int=5, @pagenumber int=2, @OrderBy varchar(20)='Name'

SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Name' THEN Name END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ProductNumber' THEN ProductNumber END
    )-1)%@pageSize+1 as N, * 
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Name' THEN Name END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ProductNumber' THEN ProductNumber END
OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @pageSize) AS RN, *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Production.Product
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Name' THEN Name END,
        CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ProductNumber' THEN ProductNumber END
    OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
) X
```

Razvan

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it in the application.